# Autocorrect spelling mistakes using Google?

Tags: vimscript, spell-checking

I found [an automation script](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/100293-autocorrect-anything/) written in AutoHotKey very inspiring. It relies on the search result from Google to correct the wrongly spelled words.

The script:

```
; Ctrl+Alt+c autocorrect selected text
^!c::
clipback := ClipboardAll
clipboard=
Send ^c
ClipWait, 0
UrlDownloadToFile % "https://www.google.com/search?q=" . clipboard, temp
FileRead, contents, temp
FileDelete temp
if (RegExMatch(contents, "(Showing results for|Did you mean:)</span>.*?>(.*?)</a>", match)) {
   StringReplace, clipboard, match2, <b><i>,, All
   StringReplace, clipboard, clipboard, </i></b>,, All
}
Send ^v
Sleep 500
clipboard := clipback
return
```

Is there a way to construct a similar function in Vim?

Comment: You can rely on external tools with vim, such as curl, grep, sed, ... So you could definitely build something like that. But rather than using Vimscript for that, I'd write a script in your prefered language and call it in Vim, parsing its output as the result. If you want to stay with Vimscript, have a look at https://github.com/mattn/webapi-vim